# VB.NET Help sectioning with distinct numbers

Tags: vb.net

What I need is this: (A, B, C, D, etc.. are chars(name of the section))

A = 0-40

B = 41-80

C = 81-120

D = 121-160

and so on

I have a combobox containing numbers from 0 to 1040, when I select numbers such as 80, the section turns into C, which should be B because it goes inside 41-80 as seen above. As well as I choose 120, it turns into D, which should be C. etc etc. Only numbers from 1-40 works perfectly. Here is my code:

```
Dim counter As String
Dim mysection As String
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    counter = cmbYearAdd.SelectedItem
    Dim a As Char = "A"
    Dim distinct1% = 1, distinct2% = 40
    For x As Integer = counter To 1040
        If x >= distinct1 And x <= distinct2 Then
            mysection = a
            Exit For
        Else
            a = Chr(Asc(a) + 1)
            distinct1 += 40
            distinct2 += 40
        End If
    Next
    lblSectionAdd.Text = "Section: " & mysection
End Sub
```

I have a label, combobox, and button.

Answer (score 2):

This is because when the limits are raised the value of `x` is incremented when the for loop starts over.
But please don't try to fix it - this method is so awkward you shouldn't put any effort in it anymore. Simply keep the counter value fixed and divide by your section size to directly compute which section the value belongs to:

```
Dim counter As String
Dim mysection As String
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    counter = cmbYearAdd.SelectedItem
    Dim a As Char = "A"
    Dim sectionsize as Integer = 40
    Dim sect as Integer  

    sect = Int((counter-1) / sectionsize)
    mysection = Chr(Asc("A") + sect)
    lblSectionAdd.Text = "Section: " & mysection
End Sub
```

The division result needs to be truncated to Integer, I'm using Int() for this.

Comment: Glad I could help. I've got no notion of VB.net BTW. If you're satisfied and  if you like you may accept my answer.